# Is there a way to specify the number of digits after AND before the decimal point in the Java Formatter

Tags: java, formatter

I am able to specify the number of digits for an int, with for example:

```
String result = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, "%08d", 5555); // result is "00005555"
```

Or the number of digits after the decimal point for a float, with for example:

```
String result = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, "%.2f", 5.2345); // result is "5.23"
```

Is it possible using the Java `Formatter` (used internally by the String class), to both specify the number of digits before AND after the decimal point?

I would like to be able to specify something like that for example:

```
String result = String.format(java.util.Locale.US, <the format>, 5.2345); // result would be "0005.23"
```

Comment: the `Formatter` syntax is well documented (IMHO) [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is in what that `%` stuff means. The format is:

`%1[MODS]x` where the '1' can be any sequence of digits, you don't have to put it there (just `%f` is legal too), and specifies the intended length **of the entire element**, it's not specific to what kind of thing you're formatting. Then the letter identifies the thing you want to do (i.e. `x` for hexadecimal, `d` for a number, `f` for a floating point number, `s` for a string, and so on), and in between the digits for 'total length of the entire element' and the letter you can put modifiers; the meaning of them and what you can do there depends on the letter chosen. But they all support that length thing, and all in the same way (length of *the entire element*).

Thus, you combine them (`%7.2f` for example), but know that the `7` would refer to the length of *the entire element*, not 'the digits before the decimal point'.

Thus, if you want 5 digits, then the decimal point, then 2 digits, that's 8 total (5+2, and the decimal point, makes 8), thus:

```
System.out.printf("%8.2f\n", 15.2555);
```

Ends up printing 8 symbols total: 3 spaces, then '1', '5', a decimal point symbol, '2', and '6'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by combining the 2: `%08.2f`

Comment: Nitpicking, that should probably be `%07.2f` for `0005.23`. Total width 7, 2 decimals and 1 postion for the dot (at least in US locale) leaves 4 digits before the dot.

Comment: also account that one digit position will be used for the sign if the number is negative (e.g. with `%07.2f`: `-005.23` - `7` is the whole length)